# Re-sizing the output of report from A4 to the cheque size in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have a report which has been formatted as the bank cheque format. When I have run it in the preview it will give the output on A4 size pdf which will create blank space. I want to re-size it to the bank cheque size to remove the blank space and print it directly on the cheque. Currently I have to print the cheque on the A4 size paper then re-print the report on the same page. Is it possible to re-size the pdf? If it is possible then where I have to mention the size of the pdf?

Report and form was created on Oracle 6i.

Attached image clarify my point. I wants to remove the space marked as red rectangle. 
[image]

Comment: Please clarify: this question is just about configuring the Preview and not about printing actual cheque.

Comment: kindly check the edits.

Comment: You have tagged Oracle10g and Oracle11g but you state in the question that it is Oracle6i - which version is it?

Comment: it is oracle 6i but I couldn't find the tags of 6i.